# Detrending fields in a structure with matlab

Tags: matlab, structure, operation

I have 10 fields in a structure, each of which have 1X1 structures, containing 18 fields.  I was wondering how to perform an operation like "detrend" on one of the 10 fields in the original structure.  This would mean detrending each of the 18 fields (these are of different lengths.  That is, I could do the following, but I want to detrend all the chunks at once.  Each chunk is of a different length.

```
detrend(ship_timeseries_chunks_S.Z180.Chunk1);
detrend(ship_timeseries_chunks_S.Z180.Chunk2);
.
.
.
detrend(ship_timeseries_chunks_S.Z180.Chunk18);
```

Comment: what should `detrend` actually do? Sorting? (well, than use `sort`). It is not even clear if it should apply to the field names or to the content of the structures...

Comment: you can concatenate them and then detrend, or perhaps arrayfun